# Making an array out of big number of matrices in r

Tags: arrays, r, matrix

I'm trying to work with arrays, but I can't seem to make one that works for my data. I have 14 matrices I would like to put in an array, but I can't figure out the way to do it without manually writing c(m1,m2,m3...) to put in all of them

this is what i tried:

```
m_list <- mget(paste0("well_", 0:13)) ###to make a list of all my matrices

a <- array(c(m_list), 
       dim = c(7338, 15, 14))
```

but when I try to look at the array I created something is not right with it cause I try to call for one value, like this:

```
print(a[1,4,2])
```

but I get entire columns.

I assume the error is in the list of matrices. Please help

Comment: `do.call(c, m_list)`; also check out the abind package.

Answer (score 0):

An answer to your question is that you should use `do.call(c, m_list)` instead of `c(m_list)`. (Take a couple of small matrices and try to see what `c(m_list)` and `c(m1, m2)` return.)

Also you might want to think some more whether working with an array is better than working with a list and, more importantly, how you could avoid having multiple matrices in the first place and instead to directly read/define them as a list or an array.

Comment: Thank you, it's working :). I figured I must be calling the data incorrectly, but wasn't familiar with this `do.call` function.

Comment: I am trying to refine my code a little bit, an I'm working really hard, but getting nowhere for days :/. I'm still not good with apply family and loops (even though I've been told to avoid loops if possible). So what you are saying is that I could start working with `m_list` directly??

Comment: @BStat, yes, sometimes that might be a good idea. It depends on what you are going to do next with your data. For learning purposes you could even have your data as an array and as a list at the same time and see what differences you encounter.

Comment: I actually took you're advice and am now trying to do both in parallel, but next thing I need to do is covert one of the columns in each matrix from UNIX time to time stamp date.time. I did on individual mat

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40112446/applying-as-posixct-function-to-a-list-of-matrices)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `unlist` inside your `array` function call instead of `c`.

```
a = array(unlist(m_list), dim = c(dim(m_list[[1]]), length(m_list)))
```

Some reproducible data:

```
m1 = matrix(1:5, 5, 5)
m2 = matrix(5:1, 5, 5)
m_list = list(m1, m2)
```